# download list of urls with scrapy, to a list of filenames, with rate-limiting

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a large list of urls I would like to download (about 400K) and I would like to use the concurrent downloading capability of scrapy. The most basic Pipeline examples I have found have been too complicated.

Can you point me to a simple example that would take a list like this:

```
url_list = ['http://www.example.com/index.html',
            'http://www.something.com/index.html']
```

and I would store them in a list of files like this:

```
file_list = ['../file1.html',
             '../file2.html']
```

Rate-limiting would be a nice bonus so as not to overload a poor server.

Note: Does not need to be with scrapy if there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify this snippet of code to do what you want:

```
import requests
import grequests

def exception_handler(request, exception):
    print "Request failed"


def chop(seq,size):
    """Chop a sequence into chunks of the given size."""
    chunk = lambda i: seq[i:i+size]
    return map(chunk,xrange(0,len(seq),size))


def get_chunk(chunk):
    reqs = (grequests.get(u) for u in chunk)
    foo = grequests.map(reqs)
    for r in foo:
        player_id = r.request.url.split('=')[-1]
        print r.status_code, player_id, r.request.url, len(r.content)
        open('data/%s.html' %player_id, 'w').write(r.content)



urls = [a.strip() for a in open('temp/urls.txt').read().split('\n') if a]

chunks = chop(urls, 150)

for chunk in chunks:
    get_chunk(chunk)
```

Comment: Oh nice! That looks much better than scrapy – and can work in python 3 too I think. Thank you.